# How do I send keys programmatically (simulated key typing) in Linux Mint?

Tags: clipboard, linux-mint, keepass, password-manager

I have passwords saved in a password manager (KeePass running on Wine) on Linux Mint.

The login site that I have does not allow pasting the password. The password is a 40 random characters and special characters which makes it difficult and tedious to type manually using keyboard.

I want to copy the password from the KeePass and then run some script (like AutoIt, AutoIt is not supported on Linux Mint) that reads the clipboard data (the copied password) and sends character by character (simulate typing by keyboard) to the password field in the browser.

How do I achieve this on Linux Mint 20? If AutoIt was working on Linux Mint I would have been happy.

I found `xdotool` but cannot figure out a way to set the focus to Firefox window.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
pass=`clipit -c`

xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --name "My Bank" windowactivate
xdotool type --delay 500 $pass
```